# Handle back button using map_view (flutter)

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, dart, flutter

I am  using the flutter plugin map_view and I have integrated this example ( https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/map_view#-example-tab- ) in my code. I have a navigation drawer with a field called "example", which leads to the page of the example linked. Here pressing the map button opens a map. While the map is open, with the back button we go back to the page with the map button. I want to bypass the map button page and go back to the the previous page, the one with the navigation drawer. How can I achieve this? I am new to Flutter.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

follow this steps :

1. First you mus have a named routes defined in your app as this :

   new MaterialApp(
     home: new Screen1(),
     routes:  {
       '/navdrawer': (BuildContext context) => new NavigationDrawerScreeen(),
       '/mapbutton' : (BuildContext context) => new MapButtonScreen(),
       '/map' : (BuildContext context) => new MapScreen(),
     },
   )
2. Navigate to your pages using `Navigator.pushNamed`.

   Navigator.pushNamed(context, "mapbutton");
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "map");
3. now you can pop back to the desired page and bypass the map button page using this code :

   Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/navdrawer'));